# Great circle on a sphere does not show up perfectly when looking at it head on

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

The following code produces the following out. What's the reason for the great circle to be broken up around the x-y plane?

```
g = Graphics3D[{},
  ImageSize -> {1000, Automatic}, 
   PlotRange -> { {-1.05, 1.05}, {-1.05, 1.05}, {-1.05, 1.05}}, 
   Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> 10^3 {0, -1, 0}, 
   Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True},
   Lighting -> {{"Ambeint", RGBColor[1, 1, 1]},
    {"Directional", RGBColor[.5, .5, .5], {{0, 0, 10}, {0, 0, 0}}},
    {"Directional", RGBColor[.25, .25, .25], {{0, -10, -10}, {0, 0, 0}}},
    {"Directional", RGBColor[.25, .25, .25], {{-10, -10, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}},
    {"Directional", RGBColor[.25, .25, .25], {{10, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}
  }
  ];

  g = Show[g,
     Graphics3D[{White, Specularity[White, 5], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]}],
     ParametricPlot3D[{0, Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> {Black, AbsoluteThickness[6]}]
  ];
```

[image]

Comment: Works for me on v12.1 on Mac, no gap visible, while v12.0 reproduces the gap.